# Is this a LL(1) grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

Considering the following grammar for propositional logic:

```
<A> ::= <B> <-> <A> | <B> 
<B> ::= <C>  -> <B> | <C> 
<C> ::= <D>  \/ <C> | <D> 
<D> ::= <E>  /\ <D> | <E> 
<E> ::= <F> | -<F>
<F> ::= <G> | <H>
<G> ::= (<A>)
<H> ::= p | q | r | ... | z
```

Precedence for conectives is: -, /\, /, ->, <->.

Associativity is also considered, for example `p\/q\/r` should be the same as `p\/(q\/r)`. The same for the other conectives.

I pretend to make a predictive top-down parser in java. I dont see here ambiguity or direct left recursion, but not sure if thats all i need to consider this a LL(1) grammar. Maybe undirect left recursion?

If this is not a LL(1) grammar, what would be the steps required to transform it for my intentions?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it?

Comment: Please, define "programming question".

Comment: A programming question would be more concerned with the code to do what you are asking about than what you are asking about.  Your question is meta if anything.

Comment: Ok, maybe this is more like a "theoretical question".

Comment: I'd file this under _Logic_ or _Math_ (the math exchange seem to have some threads on logic). No need to define it, they already did that in the help center.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate on the [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) site, since it is more theoretical and doesn't include code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not LL(1). Here's why:

The first rule of an LL(1) grammar is:

A grammar G is LL(1) if and only if whenever `A --> C | D` are two distinct productions of G, the following conditions hold:

1. For no terminal `a` , do both C and D derive strings beginning with `a`.

This rule is, so that there are no conflicts while parsing this code. When the parser encounters a `(`, it won't know which production to use.

Your grammar violates this first rule. All your non-terminals on the right hand of the same production , that is, all your Cs and Ds, eventually reduce to G and H, so all of them derive at least one string beginning with `(`.